# Top of columns uneven in HTML document

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML `<article>` with multiple columns. The first column is always 1/2 to 1 row lower than the others. I’ve tried getting rid of the heading, and everything else to try to isolate it, but I’m obviously missing something.

```html
<article id="Safety" style="padding-bottom: 40px;padding-top: 20px;padding-right:30px; padding-left: 50px;">
  <h3>Safety First: Prescription Safety Glasses</h3>
  <div style="column-count: 2; column-gap: 40px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 80px; ">
    <a href="https://my-benefits.ehr.com/US2/EN/myHealth/Vision/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="glasses.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; display: block; float: right; padding-left: 40px;"></a>
    <p>Some of my fellow eyeglass wearers may not be aware that Comcast will pay for you to have your prescription safety glasses fully covered! I recently became aware of this information and wanted to share it with all of you. Per our ComcastNow website,
      in the Vision Benefits SPD: Davis Vision will cover 100% of the cost, VSP- Safety Vision Glasses (Employee only) Coverage 100% after $20 copay; $75 Frame allowance. This helps us all, with the struggle of trying to wear two sets of glasses in order
      to see and be OSHA compliant while working in the field. More information can be found at <a href="https://my-benefits.ehr.com/US2/EN/myHealth/Vision/Pages/default.aspx">https://my-benefits.ehr.com/US2/EN/myHealth/Vision/Pages/default.aspx</a> regarding
      this great benefit. </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#contents" class="links">Back to Table of Contents</a>
</article>
```

Comment: Ok so that didn't work. Looks like I have to learn how to post so that you can see my html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove the paragraph tag or add `margin-top:0` to it

```html
<article id="Safety" style="padding-bottom: 40px;padding-top: 20px;padding-right:30px; padding-left: 50px;">
  <h3>Safety First: Prescription Safety Glasses</h3>
  <div style="column-count: 2; column-gap: 40px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 80px; ">
    <a href="https://my-benefits.ehr.com/US2/EN/myHealth/Vision/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="glasses.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; display: block; float: right; padding-left: 40px;"></a>
    <p style="margin-top:0">Some of my fellow eyeglass wearers may not be aware that Comcast will pay for you to have your prescription safety glasses fully covered! I recently became aware of this information and wanted to share it with all of you. Per our ComcastNow website,
      in the Vision Benefits SPD: Davis Vision will cover 100% of the cost, VSP- Safety Vision Glasses (Employee only) Coverage 100% after $20 copay; $75 Frame allowance. This helps us all, with the struggle of trying to wear two sets of glasses in order
      to see and be OSHA compliant while working in the field. More information can be found at <a href="https://my-benefits.ehr.com/US2/EN/myHealth/Vision/Pages/default.aspx">https://my-benefits.ehr.com/US2/EN/myHealth/Vision/Pages/default.aspx</a> regarding
      this great benefit. </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#contents" class="links">Back to Table of Contents</a>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: You should hit the check mark to the left of my answer to mark it solved

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin of 0 to your paragraph element.

```
p { margin: 0}
```